# pylab imports from shell but not when running .py file from cmd

Tags: python, shell, matplotlib, cmd

I am trying to run a *.py file from the cmd which contains an    import pylab statement, and I get an import error saying 'No module named pylab', however when running the same statement from the python shell it works fine. What could be wrong?

Comment: You are using the same python version in both cases and are calling in the same way (so not file verison through IDLE or something like that)? If so how is PYTHONPATH and if you alter it, did you export it?